# Passing variables to use through a Android project

Tags: android, variables

I am trying to pass the variable "stockSymbol" set in this part of my project...

```
ticker.setText("Stock Ticker is: " + stockSymbol);
```

to be the same value for this part of my project...

```
final String yqlURL = yahooURLFirst + stockSymbol + yahooURLSecond;
```

Here's the full code...

```
String stockSymbol = "";
```

`...`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stock_info);

    stock = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.stock);
    ticker = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ticker);
    btnquote = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnquote);
    btnquote.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // get the name from edittext and storing into string variable
            String stockSymbol = stock.getText().toString();

           // binding name to the textview
           ticker.setText("Stock Ticker is: " + stockSymbol);
       }
    });

    // Initialize TextViews
    companyNameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.companyNameTextView);
    yearLowTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yearLowTextView);
    yearHighTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yearHighTextView);
    daysLowTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.daysLowTextView);
    daysHighTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.daysHighTextView);
    lastTradePriceOnlyTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lastTradePriceOnlyTextView);
    changeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.changeTextView);
    daysRangeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.daysRangeTextView);

    // Sends a message to the LogCat
    Log.d(TAG, "Before URL Creation " + stockSymbol);

    // Create the YQL query
    final String yqlURL = yahooURLFirst + stockSymbol + yahooURLSecond;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common scope issue. You are declaring a new `StockSymbol` String inside of your `onClick` method. To fix this, simply change the line

```
String stockSymbol = stock.getText().toString();
```

to

```
stockSymbol = stock.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

In the onClick method you declare stockSymbol as a local variable.  Don't do that, instead use stockSymbol defined in the parent class.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want to go fun(?) solution. Set the variable as the tag value of the view.

```
  public void onClick(View v) {
            // get the name from edittext and storing into string variable
            String stockSymbol = stock.getText().toString();

           // binding name to the textview
           ticker.setText("Stock Ticker is: " + stockSymbol);
           ticker.setTag(stockSymbol);
       }
```

Assign the value.

```
final String yqlURL = ticker.getTag();
```

Answer (score 0):

Still doesn't seem to be taking the variable passed from my textview. Here's a more complete version of the code with the String removed from the `OnClick` listener. Edward - I tried to implement your "fun" workaround but to no avail.

```
String stockSymbol = "D";

// Used to make the URL to call for XML data
String yahooURLFirst = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22";
String yahooURLSecond = "%22)&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";

EditText stock;
Button btnquote;
TextView ticker;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stock_info);

    stock = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.stock);
    ticker = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ticker);
    btnquote = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnquote);
    btnquote.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // get the name from edittext and storing into string variable
            stockSymbol = stock.getText().toString();
            // binding name to the textview
            ticker.setText(stockSymbol);
        }
    });       

    // Initialize TextViews
    companyNameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.companyNameTextView);
    yearLowTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yearLowTextView);
    yearHighTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yearHighTextView);
    daysLowTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.daysLowTextView);
    daysHighTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.daysHighTextView);
    lastTradePriceOnlyTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lastTradePriceOnlyTextView);
    changeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.changeTextView);
    daysRangeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.daysRangeTextView);

    // Sends a message to the LogCat
    Log.d(TAG, "Before URL Creation " + stockSymbol);


    // Create the YQL query
    final String yqlURL = yahooURLFirst + stockSymbol + yahooURLSecond;
```

Comment: this is not how to show more info about your question. You need to show more, __uneditted__ code (pre-question) by editing your existing question. Furthermore, tell people that it is not working by commenting on their answers.

Comment: Please don't use an answer as responding to other answers. Either edit the original post or use a comment